# Tcp connection with Spring Integration framework

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, spring-integration

I am trying to create a Tcp server which accept inbound connection, and send message to connected clients asynchronously.
There is a sample of Tcp server but it is using gateway, which is request/response, does not support async.

my goal,

1. server listen to socket, e.g. 9000
2. a tcp client connect to 9000
3. server accept connect and receive message. (use `TcpReceivingChannelAdapter`?)
4. server keep the connection/socket and make note of the ip_connectId header.
5. when some event or schedule task produce a message for a client, it looks up the ip_connectId and send a message to that client. (use `TcpSendingMessageHandler`?)

From the reference document, I should use Collaborating Outbound and Inbound Channel Adapters. but there is no java config sample. I don't understand how to do this with java config, especially how and where to look for a client to send.

Do I need two channels? one for inbound and one for outbound? 
inboundAdapter->fromTcpChannel->consumer
producer->outboundAdapter->toTcpChannel

Do I create `ServiceActivator` or Endpoint to act as consumer/producer?
Does spring integration keep connections alive by default? and when I need to send message to it, by just adding ip_connectId header to a message?
Do I dispatch the message to client using `TcpSendingMessageHandler` or need to implement a `gateway`?

Clean up my code and test again after Gary's help, this is my code so far.

```
@EnableIntegration
@IntegrationComponentScan
@Configuration
public class IntegrationConfig implements
        ApplicationListener<TcpConnectionEvent> {
    @Value("${listen.port:8000}")
    private int port;

    @Bean  //for accepting text message from TCP, putty
    public MessageChannel fromTcp() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    @Bean  //for sending text message to TCP client, outbound
    public MessageChannel toTcp() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    // receive from MVC controller
    @Bean
    public MessageChannel invokeChannel() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }   

    @Bean  //inbound, it is working, I could read the inbound message while debugging
    public TcpReceivingChannelAdapter in(
            AbstractServerConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        TcpReceivingChannelAdapter adapter = new TcpReceivingChannelAdapter();
        adapter.setOutputChannel(fromTcp());
        adapter.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        return adapter;
    }

    //transform TCP bytes to string message, working
    @Transformer(inputChannel = "fromTcp", outputChannel = "toCollaborate")
    public String convert(byte[] bytes) {

        return new String(bytes);
    }

    MessageHeaders staticheader;  //save ip_connectinId, use this to collaborate outbound message later, for testing purpose only
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "toCollaborate", outputChannel = "toTcp")
    public Message<String> handleTcpMessage(Message<String> stringMsg) {
        staticheader = stringMsg.getHeaders();
        return stringMsg;
        // save the header, collaborate to output channel
    }

    //collaborate message from REST API invokeChannel to a outbound tcp client, this fail
    @Transformer(inputChannel = "invokeChannel", outputChannel = "toTcp")
    public Message<String> headerBeforeSend(String test) {
        GenericMessage<String> msg = new GenericMessage<String>(
                "from rest api");
        if (staticheader != null) {         
            MessageBuilder
                    .fromMessage(msg)
                    .setHeader("ip_connectionId",
                            staticheader.get("ip_connectionId")).build();
        }
        return msg;
    }

    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "toTcp")
    @Bean
    public TcpSendingMessageHandler out(
            AbstractServerConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        TcpSendingMessageHandler tcpOutboundAdp = new TcpSendingMessageHandler();
        tcpOutboundAdp.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);


        return tcpOutboundAdp;
    }   

    // should need only 1 factory? and keep connectin alive
    // server for in coming connection
    @Bean
    public AbstractServerConnectionFactory serverCF() {
        return new TcpNetServerConnectionFactory(this.port);
    }

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(TcpConnectionEvent tcpEvent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        TcpConnection source = (TcpConnection) tcpEvent.getSource();

    }

}
//The MVC controller
@Autowired
    MessageChannel invokeChannel;
    @RequestMapping(value="/invoke")
    public String sayHello()
    {
        //trigger gateway to send a message
        String msg = "hello";
        MessagingTemplate template = new MessagingTemplate();
        template.send(invokeChannel, new GenericMessage<String>(msg));      
        return msg;
    }
```

The test result:
1. putty connect ok, send text message
2. SI receive message ok
3. use REST API `localhost/webappname/rest/invoke` to send a message to invokeChannel, ok
4. The `transformer` set message header
5. exception as follow

> exception org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request
>   processing failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: Unable to find
>   outbound socket
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:981)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:860)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:845)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
>     org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes; the connection is kept open by default; yes you can use a `@ServiceActivator` to handle requests; yes you just have to set the connection id header.

To configure the outbound adapter in Java Configuration, add `@ServiceActivator` to the handler bean...

```
@Bean
public TcpReceivingChannelAdapter() in() {

    ...
    adapter.setOutputChannel(newRequests());

}


...

@ServiceActivator(inputChannel="toClientChannel")
@Bean
public TcpSendingMessageHandler out() {

    ...

}
```

Comment: Also see the `@Configuration` sample in the Reference Manual: http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/ip.html#ip-annotation

Comment: Gary, I still do not fully understand. 
When I create the `TcpSendingMessageHandler` bean, should I assign a `AbstractServerConnectionFactory` object to its parameter?
When there is a message being output to the `toClientChannel` channel, How do I get this message object inside `out()`? 
How do I send message through TCP inside this `out()` handler?

Comment: How to return a channel from `newRequest()`? my channels are defined outside of the `Endpoint` class.
@EnableIntegration
@IntegrationComponentScan
@Configuration
public class IntegrationConfig 
{
@MessageEndpoint
 public static class RelayService{
        @Bean
public TcpReceivingChannelAdapter() in() {

    ...
    adapter.setOutputChannel(newRequests());

}
}
}

Comment: I got it working, turns out I am not setting the header correctly. The message header is immutable, I have to assign the `build()` result to another message object, then return the new message.