# MessageTemplate cause no converter found exception in MVC controller?

Tags: string, spring, spring-mvc, converters

[related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35787606/tcp-connection-with-spring-integration-framework)

I am sending message from REST API to SI message channel, which delegate to a sending message adapter. The message adapter send a message to TCP client. nothing needs to be return/response. My TCP client successfully received the message but the MVC controller throw an exception

Controller code

```
@Autowired
    MessageChannel invokeChannel;
    @RequestMapping(value="/invoke/{payload}")
    public ResponseEntity<String> sayHello(@PathVariable String payload)
    {
        //trigger gateway to send a message     
        MessagingTemplate template = new MessagingTemplate();       
        template.send(invokeChannel, new GenericMessage<String>(payload));      
        return new ResponseEntity<String>(payload, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

The Exception

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No converter found for return
>   value of type: class java.lang.String
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:178)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.HttpEntityMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(HttpEntityMethodProcessor.java:183)
>     org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:80)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:126)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:814)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:737)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:969)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:860)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:845)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
>     org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

I couldn't find where and what is causing this. my breakpoint at `return new ResponseEntity(...)` is not reached.

my webmvcconfig

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@ComponentScan({ "helloworldmvc" })
public class WebappConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertyConfigIn() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }

    @Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(
            List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        converters.add(new MongoMessageConverter());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> //trigger gateway to send a message

You should be sure that your flow for the `template.send(invokeChannel)` is really **one-way**. No one gateway may wait for rely there. That is for your comment like:

> my breakpoint at `return new ResponseEntity(...)` is not reached.

If you can't reach that row of code, try to debug exactly that `AbstractMessageConverterMethodProces`. And there is need to figure out why `producibleMediaTypes` after the code:

```
    List<MediaType> producibleMediaTypes = getProducibleMediaTypes(servletRequest, clazz, type);

    if (value != null && producibleMediaTypes.isEmpty()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("No converter found for return value of type: " + clazz);
    }
```

is empty. Maybe you request uses some `Accept` non-compatible with the String? Or your `WebMvcConfigurer` overrides `List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters` somehow without any String-awere converter?

Comment: Artem, I do not know if the invokeChannel is one-way or two-way, I thought `DirectChannel` let you send message to it without knowledge of what is on the other end of the channel, is it? How do I configure it to make it one-way? I think my `WebMvcConfigurer` did overrides the `HttpMessageConverter<?>` to support JSON payload. But I thought spring default converter should still be there, maybe I was wrong.

Comment: I print out number of message converters when MVC boot, it turns out I have only 1, which is for JSON. I switch to `extendMessageConvertes()`, this gives me 7 converters. One problem remains, the `DirectChannel` seems to echo the message back to whoever sending messsage to it, is it the default behavior? how do I turn it off?

Comment: I solved it, I've add a outputChannel which was not needed, that why it is echoing back.

Comment: I'm glad to read that! Sorry, have missed your question somehow. For that I was going to ask you to share your integration config. But now it isn't important. You are the man! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Error message:

> No converter found for return value of type: class java.lang.String

It says that the MVC doesn't know which `converter` use to return the REST response from this service. to use the default converter which are available in spring.

> Please add an annotation `@ResposeBody` in the method signature.

Comment: you are right, my incorrect webMvcConfig has removed default MVC converter. Once I add them back, it works again.